# Variable in array's index not changing the its value

Tags: c

I have a array of structs called `student` and a variable `num`.

When I try to access the index `num` of the student array, it doesn't work.
When I try to print its contents, it gives `hf`

My code:

```
typedef struct {
  char subject[50];
  int grade;
} SUBJECTS;

void viewSubjects(SUBJECTS student[], int size, int *numberOfSubjects) {
  for (int i = 0; i < *numberOfSubjects; i++) {
    printf("\n%s-\t%d\n", student[i].subject, student[i].grade);
  }
}

void addSubject(SUBJECTS student[], int size, int *numberOfSubjects) {
  char newSubject[50];
  int exists = 0, grade = 0, num = (*numberOfSubjects) + 1;
  do {
    exists = 0;
    printf("What's the name of the subject?\n");
    scanf("%s", newSubject);
    for (int i = 0; i < *numberOfSubjects; i++) {
      if (strcmp(student[i].subject, newSubject) == 0) {
        exists = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
  } while (exists == 1);
  strcpy(student[num].subject, newSubject);
  do {
    printf("What was the grade for %s?\n", newSubject);
    scanf("%d", &grade);
  } while (grade < 0 || grade > 20);
  student[num].grade = grade;
  ++(*numberOfSubjects);
}

int main(void) {
  int numberOfSubjects = 1, menuAction = 1;
  SUBJECTS student[50];
  strcpy(student[0].subject, "arroz");
  student[0].grade = 19;
  do {
    menuAction = menu();
    if (menuAction == 1) {
      addSubject(student, sizeof(student) / sizeof(student[0]),
          &numberOfSubjects);
    } else if (menuAction == 2) {
      viewSubjects(student, sizeof(student) / sizeof(student[0]),
          &numberOfSubjects);
    }
  } while (menuAction != 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "it gives `hf`". What does that mean?

Comment: I don't even know, that's all it prints

Comment: Who prints? Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, include `main` and the calling code. And show the exact input and output.

Comment: Added the main function

Comment: And the other parts - exact input and output?

Comment: I'm trying to input into the structure student. The output just prints out hf

Comment: Added output function

Comment: Yes, but tell us **exactly** what you are inputting and **exactly** what the output is. That is, show your test log.

Comment: When I run the program, it goes to a function called menu, where I just choose what actions to do, so I just press 1 to invoke the function addSubject and when I'm finished, I input 2, so that it calls the function viewSubjects. It doesn't output the second subject. If I change num to a regular constant (1), it works fine

Comment: Duarte Arribas , that info is more useful in the post than deep in the comment section.  Add useful info there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addSubjects()` appends the new entry at offset `num = (*numberOfSubjects) + 1`. It should instead use the entry at offset `num = *numberOfSubjects` and test if this index is below `size` to avoid writing beyond the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I've figured it out. I was initializing `numberOfSubjects` as 1 and then adding 1, so when calling the second position, the results were unpredictable, as I changed the value in the third position (index 2).